# What do the symbols on the main menu mean?

Tags: threes

If you swipe *all* the way to the left on the menu and then some, this sequence of symbols appears. (Do not pay any mind to the white circles: it's where I was holding my finger. The space between the first few and the last three symbols is also not present in game.)

[image][image]

What gives?

Answer (score 5):

They are the characters of the game as a symbol.

- Triangle is Trin (3)
- 6 dots in a circle is Thumbert (6)
- Maybe an up-tooth? is Treycee (12)
- I think it's a sleepy face for Tristine (24)
- Buck tooth is Torbus (48)
- The sharp teeth are Traven, the "herbivore" (96)
- Headphones for Threejay (192)

and from here it's spoilers, depending on how high you've gotten.